# How to install yosemite on a new harddrive?

Tags: macos

So I am going to put a new hard drive on my Macbook Pro. After I install the hard drive how would I go about putting Yosemite on there? I have a pc and a 32gb flash drive. Could I download it through the pc onto the flash and then after I put in the new hard drive could I install from the flashdrive?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you *could* but it may or may not work. In my best opinion, I would go to an Apple Store and tell them to boot your computer on their network. They will do it for free, and it is a lot faster than sitting at home waiting for 2 hours while it downloads the OS again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an external USB enclosure, you could do what I did.

- Put the new drive in the enclosure.
- Use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/features) to clone your internal to the new drive. (Works for everything except Bootcamp partitions, for which you need [WinClone](http://twocanoes.com/winclone/))
- Swap drives.
- Done.

Not free, but solid.